# Category list in wordpress changing styles with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, list, coding-style, categories

I am using wordpress list categories function to retrieve a specific selection of categories to navigate categories. What I want to know is, is it possible to create a function that will de-activate the active category link or restyle the link to make it black or bold etc., say 12 if I am on the category page 12?

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('include=12,13,11&title_li='); ?> 
</ul>
```

I found this as a starting point

```
 <?php
if (is_category('tomato'))
{echo 'class="tomato-red"';}
if (is_category('cucumber'))
{echo 'class="cucumber-green"';}
?>
```

but not sure how I would integrate the codes together, as obvisously the list categories is one function and I'm not sure if it's possible to specificy within that code one of the includes to apply a rule to.

Thanks for any help, n00bie php person!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress wp_list_categories() function adds "current-cat" class to current category, why don't you use that with css and leave php side alone ? : )

If you want to target specific category link, then use something like that "li.cat-item-7", where 7 is ID of your category : )

More about styling wordpress categories list you can find here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists